# Select source table and expdp have different number of records

Tags: sql, oracle

I export part of a very large table using the exdp tool. But earlier I checked in the source table the number of records that meet the condition and it went out:

```
select count(*) from SCHEMA.MYTABLE where TIMESTAMP>=1388361600000 and TIMESTAMP<1393200000000;
```

1624352128

Then I export using parameters:

```
dumpfile=EKSPORT_DIR:eksport-1388361600000-1393200000000-2014_1__%U.dmp
logfile=EKSPORT_DIR:eksport-1388361600000-1393200000000-2014_1.log
tables=SCHEMA.MYTABLE
content=data_only
QUERY=SCHEMA.MYTABLE:"where TIMESTAMP>=1388361600000 and TIMESTAMP<1393200000000"
```

And in the log it is written:

```
69.17 GB 1624365208 rows
Job "SYS"."SYS_EXPORT_TABLE_03" successfully completed at Mon Oct 23 12:01:32 2017 elapsed 0 02:21:21
```

There were 13080 more records exported than select showed.

The situation is similar in other areas. You always export a little more. I know who is that way?

Comment: Is it a running system / is it possible, that records have been added in the meantime? Did you double-check by counting the source table once more after the export?

Answer (score 0):

How accurate are your stats? Since this is a large table, the stats may have become outdated. To check you can do the following:

```
select table_name,NUM_ROWS from all_tables where owner='SCHEMA' and table_name = 'MYTABLE';
```

If the row numbers mismatch, run

```
exec dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(ownname=> 'SCHEMA', tabname=> 'MYTABLE', estimate_percent=> 100);
```

This will refresh the stats on the table and provide an accurate count of rows.

For more info you can take a look at: http://www.dba-village.com/village/dvp_forum.OpenThread?ThreadIdA=40790&DestinationA=RSS

Comment: Thank you very much. I will check it soon, but it looks good.